# Normalizing a csv field in power query (M)

Tags: excel, data-modeling, powerbi

### Background

I am building a simple dashboard in the Power BI plugins for Excel (Power Query, Power Pivot & Power View) to get some experience with Power BI. The dashboard is for presenting simple time reports made by a consultant (i.e. myself). The format i want to use for inputting data is in a Excel table as follows:

```
InputData:
Date       | Timecode  | Duration[hrs] | Tags
-----------|-----------|---------------|----------------------
2016-02-01 | CustomerA | 1.2           | Support;ProductA
2016-02-01 | CustomerB | 0.3           | Support;ProductB
2016-02-02 | Internal  | 4.2           | Development;ProductA
```

The `Date` field is simple. The date that the time report is for. The `Timecode` is the "name" of the hours reported. In common software this is usually a Project code or similar, but i want to keep it on a customer basis. The `Duration` is a float representing the number of hours spent for that Timecode that day. The `Tags` column is the interesting part: to simplify input is want it to be a (semicolon) delimited string, but that wont do when creating a data model for Power view.

What I am trying to make is a separate table with the all the tags, and a link table to connect the tags to the corresponding rows from the time report. In the Power view report, I want to be able to filter my time reports on the tags, such as analyzing the time spent on  `ProductA` or `Support`.

### Question

How do you take a non-normalized field such as `Tags` above and replace it with a dimension table and a link-table, using Power BI plugins for Excel? How do I end up with the following Three tables:

```
TimeReport:
Date       | Timecode  | Duration[hrs] | TimeReportID
-----------|-----------|---------------|----------------------
2016-02-01 | CustomerA | 1.2           | 1
2016-02-01 | CustomerB | 0.3           | 2
2016-02-02 | Internal  | 4.2           | 3

LinkTable:
TimeReportID | TagID  
-------------|--------
1            | 1
1            | 2
2            | 1
2            | 3
3            | 4
3            | 2

TagsTable:
TagID  | TagName  
-------|----------
1      | Support 
2      | ProductA
3      | ProductB
4      | Development
```

### Attempt

By picking out only the Tags-column and then splitting, pivoting and removing duplicates (inspired by [this link](http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2013/08/16/some-power-querym-examples/) i have managed to create the list of all tags as in:

```
Tags:
TagName
----------
Support
ProductA
ProductB
Development
```

But I cant manage to understand how to link the tables to eachother. Please aid me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have 2 options:

1. using Power Query, add Merge & Expand Column steps to join TimeReport to LinkTable and then TagsTable
2. using Power Pivot, load all 3 tables then go to the Diagram view and establish relationships between them.  Use "Hide from Client Tools" to hide the columns that are meaningless to the User e.g. TagID

I prefer Power Query as the functionality is more flexible and it is much easier to debug.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the tip! Assuming that I have the tables created, I agree that you approach is a good way to combine it. I was planning to do your approach 2. By I still have not managed to create the LinkTable. Any idea?

Comment: It's probably unnecessary. I would first add an Index column to your TimeReport query, then start a TagsTable query by reference to TimeReport. In TagsTable, remove all columns besides Index and Tags, then Split Tags, then select Index and Unpivot Other Columns. In Power Pivot your relationship will be on Index.

Comment: Super! Thank you! :)